# Install of Mapnik on Windows Python

Tags: python, windows, openstreetmap, mapnik

For my [master's degree](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/master%27s_degree#Noun) thesis, I have to render some maps from [OpenStreetMap](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/master%27s_degree#Noun) information. Unfortunately, I'm not able to install Mapnik.

In [the manual](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/WindowsInstallation), it said I should Add ";C:\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib" to the PATH variable. In my case, it is "C:\Users\User\Mapnik\lib". I cloned the Git repository and updated it to v3.0.23. Like it said on [the download page](https://mapnik.org/pages/downloads.html).
But in this location, I don't have *lib*. Also, I don't have *bin*. So I'm a little bit confused about how to install Mapnik.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Some more information: the OS is [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10). For Python, I'm using [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) with a 2.7 instance just for Mapnik... even if I read that I could go with Python 3. For the rest of my code, I go with Python 3.8. For sure I would prefer to stay at 3.8, but if it only works with 2.7 I would also use that.

Error message:

```
(Mapnik) C:\Users\User\Mapnik\demo\python>python rundemo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rundemo.py", line 25, in <module>
    import mapnik
ImportError: No module named mapnik
```